# PHP/MySQL join with CSV array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, csv

I have a tricky (well for me it is) question about getting info from 2 different tables.

I have an array, like this:

```
$abc=$_COOKIE['cookie'];
$comma_separated = implode(",", $abc);
```

Now, the array will be a CSV list of ID's that need to match ID's from the "Specials" table. In the "Specials" table there is a column called Contract Name. This Contract Name column needs to match a column of the same name, each unique, in the Products table, and display the information contained therein.

My currenty MySQL query looks like this:

```
$query= "SELECT specials.id,
   specials.product_name,
   specials.contract_name,
   specials.included_value AS inc_val,
   specials.image_url,
   specials.contract_monthly,
   specials.outlet,
   products.package,
   products.bundled,
   products.included_value
FROM specials,
     product

WHERE `id` IN ('.$comma_separated.')
AND specials.contract_name = `products.package`";
```

What happens is... that nothing happens. I've tried wrapping my brain around some of the JOIN tutorials but no luck.

So basically I'd like to display a list of current specials, along with the package info, which is contained in a different table. I've tried wrapping my brain around some of the JOIN tutorials but no luck.

To my knowledge I'm crap at explaining things properly, so please do shout if I can shed any more light on this conundrum.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be \`products`.`package\` or (even better) products.package. And try adding this line ... echo $query;

Comment: **product** lacks 's' in `FROM specials, product`

Comment: Also, I'm disappointed that none of those JOIN tutorials mentioned inclusion of the word "JOIN" :-(

Comment: assuming this is not a php issue, try to just post the query outputted by php and also your database schema while you are at it, so we can construct a working sqlfiddle for you and us to test.

Answer (score 0):

To even start to get this to work, your `$query` string is going to have to be a valid query. Ordinarily, to troubleshoot this kind of problem, you do `echo $query;` somewhere along the way to see if it is valid.  You then might even paste the query's textinto a standalone MySQL client (phpMyAdmin, or maybe HeidiSQL or something) to see what you get.

Looking at this line:

```
WHERE `id` IN ('.$comma_separated.')    /* wrong! */
```

it looks like it needs to read

```
WHERE `id` IN (".$comma_separated.")
```

because you're using double quotes to surround your fragments of SQL text. Also, you might want to use

```
WHERE `specials`.`id` IN (".$comma_separated.")
```

just because some other tables might contain `id` columns and then your search clause will be ambiguous.